# how to Show Sweet Alert with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-core

I want a Sweet Alert to be displayed after successful registration and to go to another page by pressing the button that is in Sweet Alert.I wrote the code to some extent, but if the model is invalid, Sweet Alert is still displayed, and the code is inconsistent. please guide me

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult submitPersons(Person person ,String newPersonCartMlieImagePath, String newPersonShnasnameeImagePathName, String newPersonImagePathName, String newPersonBieemeDacumenPath)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var proMapped = _mapper.Map<Person>(person);

        proMapped.PersonImage = newPersonImagePathName;
        proMapped.PersonShnasnamee = newPersonShnasnameeImagePathName;
        proMapped.PersonCartMlie = newPersonCartMlieImagePath;
        proMapped.PersonBieemeDacument = newPersonBieemeDacumenPath;
        proMapped.PersonState = true;

        _context.Add(proMapped);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("allPerson");
    }

    ViewBag.pro = _context.Projects.ToList();

    return View("submitPerson", person);

}

<button id="btn-submit-btn" value="Submit" type="submit">ثبت پرسنل</button>



<script>

    $('#btn-submit-btn').click(function () {
        swal({
            title: "ارسال نامه",
            text: "نامه شما با موفقیت ارسال شد",
            type: 'success',
            showCancelButton: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            confirmButtonColor: "green",
            confirmButtonText: "باشه"
        }).then(function () {
            window.location.href = "/Home/allPerson";
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the Model is valid,if valid,add swal to onclick event:

```
@if (Model is valid)//check Model is valid or not here
{
    <button id="btn-submit-btn" value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="click1()">ثبت پرسنل</button>
}
else
{
    <button id="btn-submit-btn" value="Submit" type="submit">ثبت پرسنل</button>
} 
<script>
function click1() {
            swal({
                title: "ارسال نامه",
                text: "نامه شما با موفقیت ارسال شد",
                type: 'success',
                showCancelButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                confirmButtonColor: "green",
                confirmButtonText: "باشه"
            }).then(function () {
                window.location.href = "/Home/allPerson";
            });
        }
</script>
```